# If comparing by type is bad design, what am I do do in this situation? (Polymorphism)

Tags: c++, oop, uml, class-diagram

I have an assignment where I have to write a UML class diagram for the Donkey Kong Original game.

In the game, there are small cutscenes where particular Entities(Subclasses of Entity) are manipulated. Hence I have made a Cutscene class to manage this. My issue is, I don't want to include all my entity subclasses into Cutscene because it seems unnecessary to me (It will also make my UML diagram look messy :p). Id rather just have my Cutscene include my Entity class, then pass in my sub-entities as enemies to do checks to see which entity I'm dealing with so I can manipulate them appropriately. (It seems cleaner?).

However, I read here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/21246/ that it's bad design to have to use polymorphism this way. I do appear to be using it for a different purpose however.

If anyone could tell me if I'm a fool and what I should be doing, that would be greatly appreciated!

[image: URL Diagram]

Comment: Your question is to vague. You need to show us how your classes really look.

Comment: Where do you think your classes use polymorphism?

Comment: I'm voting to Migrate this question to [programmers stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) where it is on topic.

Comment: @Serdalis when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: yeah sorry for wrong section, im a noob

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check the type of an Entity instance, have a look at the 'Visitor' pattern that is a solution for doing double dispatching in C++.

```
class EntityVisitor {
    virtual void Visit(const Ladder& ladder) = 0;
    virtual void Visit(const Mario& mario) = 0;
    ...
};
```

Your 'Entity' would have a pure virtual function that takes a 'Visitor'.

```
virtual Accept(EntityVisitor& visitor) = 0;
```

And each subclass implements this method passing *this to the visitors 'Visit' function.

```
void Mario::Accept(EntityVisitor& v) { 
    v.Visit(*this); // Calls the 'Mario' overload.
}
```

Comment: Thank  you, this seems like a feasible solution to what I'm trying to achieve. Reading into it now.